# Adding new Node to a linked list with two classes

Tags: c++

When trying to add a new `Node` to the liked list it gives me a `Segmentation fault`. Can someone tell me what is wrong in the implementation of the `addBook()` function. I am not sure if it's the implementation of the function that is wrong, or the way that I've declared the classes.

```
class Reservation {
        public:

    int getID();
    string getResevNum();

    void setId(int x);
    void setReseNum(string y);

    private:
        int ID;
        string reservedNumber;
};

class ReservationCollection {
    public:
    ReservationCollection();
    ~ReservationCollection();

    int getUserId(int &id);
    string getUserBook(string &bookCall);

    void findReservation();
    void display();

    void addBook(int id, string book);
    void RemoveBook();
    void ShutDown();

    private:
        struct Node {
            Reservation *data;
            Node *next;
            };
        Node *head;
 };

ReservationCollection::ReservationCollection() {
    Node *head = new Node;
    head->next = NULL;  
}

ReservationCollection::~ReservationCollection() {
}

void ReservationCollection::addBook(int id, string book){
    Node *tmp = new Node;

    tmp->data->setId(id);
    tmp->data->setReseNum(book);
    tmp->next = head->next;
    head->next = tmp;
    cout <<"Good\n";
}

int Reservation::getID(){
    return ID;
}

string Reservation::getResevNum(){
    return reservedNumber;
}
void Reservation::setId(int x){
    ID = x;
}

void Reservation::setReseNum(string y){
    reservedNumber = y;
}

int ReservationCollection::getUserId(int &id){
    cout << "Enter Id number " << endl;
    cin >> id;
    return id;
}

string ReservationCollection::getUserBook(string &bookCall){
    cout << "Enter book reservatin " << endl;
    cin >> bookCall;
    return bookCall;
}

int main()
{
    int ID;
    string BookNum;
    char cmd;

    do {
        cout << "Enter command: ";
        cin >> cmd;

        ReservationCollection list;
        if (cmd == 'A' || cmd == 'a'){

            list.getUserId(ID);
            list.getUserBook(BookNum);

            list.addBook(ID, BookNum);
        }
        else if (cmd == 'S' || cmd == 's'){
            cout << " list";
        }
    } while (cmd != 'Q' || cmd == 'q');

}
```

Comment: You have too many errors here. One was pointed out in answer. Then `Reservation *data;` is not allocated, you just declare it as pointer. You should start with a simple link list. Don't use console input for now. Just embed the input in to the code to make it faster to run the program. Also increase the warning level on your compiler.

Comment: Node *tmp = new Node();                                                                             
 tmp-> data = new Reservation(id, book);
 will this going to allocate the data pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use pointers if you don't have to. In this example `Node` has to be a pointer, because the list may have zero nodes, or 1000 nodes, so we need pointers to dynamically allocate memory on demand.

But `(Reservation)data` does not have to be a pointer. Each node always has one `Reservation` member.

If you do declare it as pointer then you must allocate it, and free it when it is no longer needed.

`head` should be initialized to `NULL`, because the single linked-list has no nodes when it is initialized. The first node inserted becomes the head.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Reservation 
{
private:
    int ID;
    string reservedNumber;
public:

    int getID() { return ID; }
    string getResevNum() { return reservedNumber; }

    void setId(int x) { ID = x; }
    void setReseNum(string y) { reservedNumber = y; }
};

class ReservationCollection
{
public:
    struct Node
    {
        Reservation data;
        Node *next;
    };

    ReservationCollection();
    ~ReservationCollection();

    void addBook(int id, string book);

    Node* getHead() { return head; }

private:
    Node *head;
};

ReservationCollection::ReservationCollection()
{
    head = NULL;
}

ReservationCollection::~ReservationCollection()
{
    Node *p = head;
    while (p)
    {
        Node *next = p->next;
        cout << "delete: " << p->data.getID() << ", " << p->data.getResevNum() << endl;
        delete p;
        p = next;
    }
}

void ReservationCollection::addBook(int id, string book)
{
    Node *node = new Node;
    node->data.setId(id);
    node->data.setReseNum(book);

    //this element is the last element
    node->next = NULL;

    if (!head)
    {
        //first element inserted
        head = node;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        //find the previous node in the list
        Node *prev = head;
        while (prev->next)
            prev = prev->next;

        //this node is after previous node
        prev->next = node;
    }

    cout << "Good\n";
}

int main()
{
    ReservationCollection list;
    list.addBook(0, "Book0");
    list.addBook(1, "Book1");
    list.addBook(2, "Book2");
    list.addBook(3, "Book3");

    ReservationCollection::Node *p = list.getHead();

    while (p)
    {
        ReservationCollection::Node *next = p->next;
        cout << p->data.getID() << ", " << p->data.getResevNum() << endl;
        p = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wish I could just comment this:

All instances of the line `Node *tmp = new Node;` should read `Node *tmp = new Node();`

Comment: Check out Shemirani's comment above.  This may not be your only error.  You are declaring a pointer to an object, and not the object itself.  When you call 'new' you need to call the constructor explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Node wont create the structure that Reservation *data; tries to point to, and so you try to access non initialized memory.
You need to initialize data:
tmp->data = new Reservation();